# Django advanced queries

Tags: django

I have 3 models: `Pupils`, `Instructor`, `Group`. They are connected through the `Pupils` model like so:

```
class Pupils(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, blank=True, default=None, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

1. How do I write a property for `Group` model which returns all `Instructor`s that have pupils from the current group? The best I can do for now is find all instructors that have any pupils:

   ```
   @property
   def instructors(self):
       from pupils.models import Instructor
       return list(Instructor.objects.filter(pupils__isnull=False).values())
   ```
2. How do I count the number of `Pupils` from the current `Group` for each `Instructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 3 models: Pupils, Instructor, Group. They are connected through
>   the Pupils model like so:

This means that you have a M2M relation between `Instructor` and `Group` which you can define like this:

```
class Instructor:
    #...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='Pupils')
```

Now using this M2M relation, you can take an `instructor` groups like this:

```
instructor.groups.all()
```

you can also use the `reverse relation` of the M2M relation in order to get all instructors for a group.

```
group.instructor_set.all()
```

you can also get the instructors count by using `.count()`

```
#group instructors count
group.instructor_set.count()
#or if you want to count pupils, 
#use the reverse relation of the ForeignKey
#group.pupils_set.count()
```

Now about the 2nd part of the question if I understand it correctly you need something like this:

```
#this will give you instructors of a group with their pupils count.
group.instructor_set.annotate(pupils_count=Count('pupils'))
```